# Add sub-section to a meal planner

Tags: python

I've been working on a "Meal Planner" project. I've been looking to add a sub-section. For the main choice, there is a 1-8 list of different food types like cereal or burgers. From that choice, I want it to go "what type of cereal?" and "good choice! you picked [cerealtype]!

This is my current code.

```
def get_menu_choice(menu_items):
    """
    This function displays a menu of choices, asks the user to choose a valid option,
    and returns the number of the menu item chosen.
    """
    # Display menu options
    for index, item in enumerate(menu_items):
        print(index+1, item)

    # Get user's choice
    user_input = input("Enter your choice: ")

    # Validate user's choice
    while not user_input.isdigit() or int(user_input) < 1 or int(user_input) > len(menu_items):
        user_input = input("Please enter a valid choice: ")

    return int(user_input)

def main():
    # Define menu options
    menu_items = ["Cereal", "French Continental", "English Breakfast", "Chicken Meals", "Pizzas","Burgers","Pastas","Toppings & Toast Special"]

    choice = get_menu_choice(menu_items)
    print("You chose:", menu_items[choice-1], "! Great choice!")

main()

def secondary():
  cereal = ["Cocoa Puffs", "Crunchy Nut", "Kellogg's", "Honey Nut Cheerios", "Weetabix"]
  french_cont = ["Crepes", "Pancakes", "Croissant"]

cerealinput = input("What specific cereal would you like?")

def get_cereal_choice(cereal):
    """
    This function displays a menu of choices, asks the user to choose a valid option,
    and returns the number of the menu item chosen.
    """
    # Display menu options
    for index, item in enumerate(cereal):
        print(index+1, item)
```

I've tried to add on to the code which picks up what was said but I can't do it.

Comment: It's pasted weird. I don't know why.

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: Please fix your code block. The easiest solution is to paste the code, then select it and click the "code block" button.

Answer (score 0):

What I see, first of all, is that the main() call happens, then there's more function definitions below it: `def secondary()` and `def get_cereal_choice(cereal)`.  These functions are never defined, because the code never gets that far into the script.
Recall that python in interpreted.  So, the first reccomendation I have is to use the more pythonic **MaGiC** of:

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

at the end of the file.  This **mAgIcAl** `if` statment will call `main()` if the current file was the one passed to python at invocation.

Otherwise there's no real question here.